Kotlin code to send SMSs without user intervention with registerForActivityResult
I'm pretty new to Kotlin (just some months) and I'm trying to develop an App that sends SMS and registers the result.
I've seen that for registering the result I have to use registerForActivityResult, but when I call callLauncher.launch I have to provide an Intent.
I tried to do it using this code:
val uriSms = Uri.parse("smsto:3292100441")
val intentSMS = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uriSms)
intentSMS.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text")
callLauncher.launch(intentSMS)

It works but it doesn't send the SMS, it just open default SMS messaging app and the user has to click on OK to send the message.
How can I make the App sending the SMS without user intervention?
The suggestion I found in Kotlin code Send SMS from within App without using default app works (the code is able to send SMS without user intervention) but as far as I know it can’t be used with registerForActivityResult that requires an Intent

Note that sending SMS without user intervention requires the SEND_SMS permission, and you may need to justify your use of this permission when you distribute your app on the Play Store or elsewhere.

Thanks @CommonsWare, I'm developing a test App, I don't need to distribute it

The question is still declared as "Duplicate" but it isn't, I added a clarification in the bottom of the question

There is no way to send an SMS without user involvement via an Intent.

:-( so I can’t use registerForActivityResult

Correct. If you want to send an SMS without user involvement, you need to use SmsManager, as is covered in the duplicate question.
